# error in releasing the static array in debug mode

Tags: c++, arrays

Why it has error in releasing  the static array in debug mode?

```
int main()
{
 int ar[] = { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 };
 //other code

 delete(ar);
 // or free(ar);

 return 0;
}
```

I used `free` or `delete` to release the array and it finished with error in `debug mode`.
Do i use the `free` or `delete` correctly?
How can i release the array?

Comment: You cannot dynamically deallocate variables allocated on stack. You can only use "delete" if you used "new" first.

Comment: Is there a way to release that array?

Comment: Well it is deleted after it goes out of scope - so after `return 0;` in your example.

Comment: I use many arrays in other functions and it need to release.

Comment: ***How can i release the array?*** You can not release the stack space occupied by the array without the current function exiting. Maybe you want  to switch to using  `std::vector`.

Answer (score 3):

`ar[]` is not allocated on the heap, but local/on the stack, so can't be (and shouldn't be) deleted.

The memory is *released* on function (or block `{}`) exit.

You can only use `delete` with `new` or `free()` with `malloc()`

Answer (score 2):

the `delete` operator and 'free' function are to be used only on pointers that
own memory allocated on the heap. your array is allocated on the stack, and
the internal implementation will crash when it will not find any heap structure.

moreover, delete is only to be applied on memory allocated with new
and free only on memory allocated with malloc,calloc or realloc.

last thing is that when you use delete on an array, use `delete []` for
this means that the removal will take place on an earlier offset on the stack,
when the record of the array itself is allocated, doing otherwise might end with a memory leak or worse